# Bootstrap table row offset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a really strange effect. I create a table with two rows. The second row is somehow shifted magically 1 cell to the right. 
[Try it](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDJS6M68XZIP).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="row">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why does this effect appear? How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `.row` has a special definition in bootstrap - you shouldn't use it for a table row. With this class, a pseudo element is added to the element with these settings:

```
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::before, .btn-toolbar::after, .btn-toolbar::before, .clearfix::after, .clearfix::before, .container-fluid::after, .container-fluid::before, .container::after, .container::before, .dl-horizontal dd::after, .dl-horizontal dd::before, .form-horizontal .form-group::after, .form-horizontal .form-group::before, .modal-footer::after, .modal-footer::before, .modal-header::after, .modal-header::before, .nav::after, .nav::before, .navbar-collapse::after, .navbar-collapse::before, .navbar-header::after, .navbar-header::before, .navbar::after, .navbar::before, .pager::after, .pager::before, .panel-body::after, .panel-body::before, .row::after, .row::before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```

This creates a conflict in a regular table.

So, just erase the "row" class from your `tr` tag to avoid this (i.e. use a class with another name if you need one).